# Phpstorm - phpDoc inspection - how to force parameter type declaration?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc, inspections

I would like to inspect in PhpStorm if method phpDoc has declared type for each parameter, eg:

```
/**
* @param @value
**/
public function someMethod($value)....
```

Would be invalid as @param $value is missing type, valid example:

```
/**
* @param string @value
**/
public function someMethod($value)
```

Comment: Please vote for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17482

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP Code sniffer in phpstorm ([install](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/using-php-code-sniffer-tool.html)).

And If you use symfony framework you can use [Symfony2 standard](https://github.com/djoos/Symfony2-coding-standard)

If not you can use one rule what actually what you want [MissingParamComment](https://github.com/djoos/Symfony2-coding-standard/blob/master/Symfony2/ruleset.xml#L87)